# Nested Stand-Alone with flash cards not working

Tags: standalone, preamble, nesting, xepersian, flashcards

I have made flash cards using the flacards document class, but they are from multiple topics across multiple semesters. I want to be able to have a unique footer for each topic/semester, as well as the page breaking once a new topic of words comes up, and the card numbers to reset.

For this, I want to use the standalone package. I want to have 1 main file, into which I import the standalone 'semester' files. Each semester file then imports a standalone topic file.

However, no matter what I do to the preamble of each individual file, I just cannot get it to work.
I've put all other files but 1 in comments, to isolate it, there's just *something* wrong. Does the flashcard environment just not work with standalone packages?

My main file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[standalone,frontgrid,backgrid,letterpaper,12pt]{flacards}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
 \begin{document}
\input{Persian_1}
\end{document}
```

The Persian_1 file then is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{ScheherazadeNew-Regular.ttf}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\input{Persian_1_Files/1_Attributive_Adjectives}
\end{document}
```

I have a folder named 'Persian_1_Files' in which I have saved all the .tex files for each individual type of word I need to learn. In this topic, I have the following:

```
\documentclass[frontgrid,backgrid,letterpaper,12pt]{flacards}
\pagesetup{3}{6}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=1]{ScheherazadeNew-Regular.ttf}
%\settextfont[Scale=1]{Neirizi.ttf}
\renewcommand{\cardtextstylef}{\Huge}
\renewcommand{\cardtextstyleb}{\large}
\renewcommand{\frfoot}{\hskip-0.15\linewidth\thecardno}
\renewcommand{\brfoot}{\hskip0.15\linewidth\thecardno}
\renewcommand{\cardtextstyleb}{\latin}

\begin{document}
\card{خوشحال}{Happy}
\end{document}
```

The file "1_Attributive_Adjectives" is only 1 word long here for ease of operation. No matter what I do, I just can't get this to work. Am I mixing the preambles up or something?

Comment: Goedemorgen! When you say "I can't get this to work" what do you mean exactly? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the text of the error? Or wrong output, if so, which output do you get and why is this wrong?

Comment: Good question, I do need to be clearer here: It depends on what I try to do.
The exact error I get now is:

'Package fontspec Error: The font "/ScheherazadeNew-Regular" cannot be found.'

This error persists even if I remove all references to the font and try to load empty files.
Using the LaTex template for standalone packages doesn't work either - it just does not seem to want to work with flash cards.

Comment: Maybe the missing font is still mentioned in one of the temporary/auxiliary files that are generated by this setup. Try to delete all of those files and/or copy the `.tex` files to a new folder and try again. Or install the font and load it in such a way that it can be found, of course.